# unable to make background colored for a rectange on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I added this lines in order to make color of border and background GREEN for a rectangle, but without success:

```
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();
context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.stroke();
```

Here my code in JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/f5z8qtcp/1/

How to make the green rectangle colored too in the background ... grey rectangle while creating it must be like it is, i want just to color the result (Border already colored to green).

Thank's.

Comment: First, tell what you exactly need...

Comment: When i create a rectangle on the canvas, this one created with transparent background and green border ... i want it with green background and border both.

Comment: Actually the border is red and my solution filled background with green.

Comment: I don't want to fill the CANVAS background, and want fill the rectangle background ! Please click with your mouse into the red canvas and move it ... you will be able to create rectangles into the red canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fillRect` function:

```
function drawAll(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.strokeStyle='green';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
    var r=rects[i];
    ctx.strokeRect(r.left,r.top,r.right-r.left,r.bottom-r.top);
    ctx.fillRect(r.left,r.top,r.right-r.left,r.bottom-r.top);
  }
}
```

Comment: This not work ! this make all the canvas colored to green, check here: https://jsfiddle.net/f5z8qtcp/2/